# Neo4j suitable for BI purposes?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, business-intelligence, anomaly-detection

I am designing a project that takes all the data from the different systems ( HR, Attendance, ERP, etc..) in the organization (ETL process for the data) and then I want to put the data in a database for BI purposes and anomaly detection purposes.

I have no experience in Graph DBs and i am wondering if neo4j is a good solution to build the DB? I want to have the ability to compare each employee to his past as well as to his colleagues. e.g. I want to know if his arrival and leaving pattern is changing in comparison for his past and is it different from his colleagues.... as well as comparing the rest of the data (his age against other colleagues age. his education vs their education... etc)

does neo4j can support such queries? is it a good use case for it? (because graphs make sense in the organization when you need to know the relations if the individuals in an organization)

Comment: In short, yes, Neo4j supports such queries. IMO Neo4j is a good use when you want to combine different data sources in one database and query them.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're trying to do is [organizational network analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_network_analysis). [AIHR Analytics' site](https://www.analyticsinhr.com/blog/what-people-analytics-can-learn-from-dynamic-network-theory/) looks like they have some information on how it's used in an HR context.

Basically what you'd do is set up a graph where each employee is a node with whatever properties you'd want to analyze (start date, end date, age, education, etc). Then you'd search for an employee, connect to immediate colleagues, colleagues of colleagues, and out as far as you desire. Finally, compare properties of the employee and the colleagues.

I'd recommend keeping the graph as simple as possible to start (just have employees connected to other employees), then add complexity (such as other kinds of nodes, like absentee dates or technical skills) as you become more familiar with Cypher and how graph databases work. Neo4j has an [article for beginners](https://neo4j.com/blog/graph-theory-predictive-modeling/) to get your feet wet.